# Values of an algebraic curve

Tags: plotting

Using

```
tmp = ContourPlot[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, -5, 
   5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

How can I get the pair values used to plot these two curves?

For example: `x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0 , (2,Sqrt(-3))` is a point of the curve.

Thank you.

Comment: For example, (2,√−3) is a point of the curve defined by x^2 + y^2 − 1 = 0 and the usual unit circle is the real part of this curve. The term "unit circle" may refer to all the complex points as well to only the real points, the exact meaning being usually clear from the context. The equation x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0 defines an algebraic curve, whose real part is empty.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : I wish to see the entire set or a part of the pairs (x1,y1) , (xn,yn) of a ContourPlot and not to save it to a file. Thanks.

Comment: Let me try to explain again: How can I get the values used to plot the two algebraic curves in the original plot? The 'duplicate question' don't have the answer I am asking for.

Comment: The `Cases` command in the answer to the duplicate yields the points (pairs) you seek.  The answer says nothing about saving to a file -- the `Export` command is irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You mean _"the question"_, for sure

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Reduce[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, y},  Cubics -> True]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'd noticed that you answered a question about interceptation of two curves. It is exactly what I want to do also. I'm reading a book where it asks to show how many times the curves intercept at the origin. I was able to find it using Sage but I'm new to Mathematica, so, I don't know how to use the Cases (yes, I read the help) neither how to use a kind of Solve or to test how many times curve1 == curve2 at (0,0).

Comment: @belisarius : almost that!

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier I see, I think: You want the points of intersection?  That's not what the question asks as currently stated.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can I rename the question or should I create another one?

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier I suppose either way would be fine -- no one has answered this one so far.

Comment: I recommend renaming; there is no benefit to creating a new Question when there are not existing answers that would be invalidated by an edit.